# Use variable grafana in query with LIKE

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables, grafana

I'm trying to create a query in [GRAFANA](https://grafana.com/) with LIKE using the internal variables of the tool, but it informs the value of the variable with `''` and this is generating an error in the query within postgres, any suggetions?

*QUERY:*

```
select count(*) from table_name where column_name like ('%'$VARIABLE'%') LIMIT 1
```

*OUTPUT:*

```
pq: syntax error at or near "'VALUE_VARIABLE'"
```

Comment: `like ('%' || $VARIABLE || '%')`?

Comment: Returned: pq: operator does not exist: character varying ~~ record

Comment: Is this select inside a string, that you pass to the dbms?

Comment: This select step within a panel to display the count value

Comment: $VARIABLE and filled by SELECT name FROM table_name

Comment: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/reference/templating/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
select count(*) from table_name where column_name like concat ('%', $VARIABLE, '%') LIMIT 1
```