# How to use like in MySQL query in Grafana?

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, grafana

I am working in grafana with MySQL. I have a template variable and it has multiple values and I want to use that template variable with MySQL query using 'like' keyword.

For Example:

```
select column_name from table_name where column_name like ('%'$Variable'%');
```

Here I ended up with Mysql syntax error or query failed in grafana.

I am looking the same as this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60814434/use-variable-grafana-in-query-with-like)

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate `$Variable` with the wildcards:

```
select column_name 
from table_name 
where column_name like concat('%', $Variable, '%');
```

Answer (score 0):

.... where column_name in ($Variable) ;